# Multiple arguments for method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, method-missing

I have the following `method_missing` code implemented in a model:

```
# class Thought
  def self.method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
    if $CLIENT.respond_to?(method_id)
      $CLIENT.send(method_id, *arguments, &block)
      # Do some stuff with it
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

`$CLIENT` is a global object. Note that this is `method_missing` for the **class**, not the instance.

I tried the following in script/console:

```
>> $CLIENT.respond_to?(:my_thoughts)
=> true
>> $CLIENT.send(:my_thoughts, 'bob', 5)
=> #<#<Class:01xe229be>:0x241391>
>> Thought.send(:my_thoughts, 'bob', 5)
ArgumentError: wrong # of arguments(1 for 2)
        from [filepath]:50:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):4
```

Is there something painfully obvious I'm missing here? I'm running this on Rails 2.3.8 and jRuby if that makes a difference.

**Edit**: This confuses me even more:

```
>> Thought.send(:my_thoughts, 'bob', 5, 5)
ArgumentError: wrong # of arguments(3 for 2)
        from [filepath]:50:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):23
```

Replacing the second argument with something other than an Integer appears to work, but of course the argument is supposed to be an Integer... I am now suspecting a problem in either jRuby or the Java classes I integrated into this.

Comment: Thanks for your edit - I was going to say, this isn't the whole story.  I tested the code you gave above, and it works fine.  the actual line 50 from the file with method_missing would reveal a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was actually with the part I omitted from above:

```
$CLIENT.send(method_id, *arguments, &block).collect |item|
```

Apparently it had a method "collect" defined which took 2 arguments, which tricked me into thinking it was Enumerable...go figure.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided works for me on both ruby-1.8.7 as well as ruby-1.9.2, so it sounds like there's a bug in the version of jRuby you're using. For completeness, this is the code I ran:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Client
    def my_thoughts(person, val)
        puts "#{person} is thinking #{val}"
    end
end

$CLIENT = Client.new

class Thought
    def self.method_missing(method_id, *arguments, &block)
        if $CLIENT.respond_to?(method_id)
            $CLIENT.send(method_id, *arguments, &block)
            # Do some stuff with it
        else
            super
        end
    end
end

Thought.send(:my_thoughts, 'bob', 5)
```

Comment: I just tested with jruby 1.5.3 (installed via rvm) and it worked as well.

Comment: Turns out the problem was due to an assumption I made regarding the Java library I was using, sorry for wasting your time.